# Do not export attached Javadoc archive in runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a project with multiple attached libraries. For few of them, I have linked their respective Javadoc contained in JAR archives. When I export it to a runnable JAR, my app weights more due to that external javadoc.

I export my project following the wizard `File > Export... > Runnable JAR file` in Eclipse, and then use the option `Package required libraries into generated JAR`.

When viewing the result in my archive manager, I have all these heavy 3rd-party javadoc packaged within my app.

How could I declare not to export these unneeded javadoc files inside my final app? I try to minimize the storage footprint of my app.

Thanks for your inputs!